# Plotly in R passing a variable through using a function

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to create a ring chart using `plotly` through a function so I can change variables around.

The following code returns **no chart**, but no errors either:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

function_ringchart<- function(dataset, labvar, summvar){
summvar_temp <- enquo(summvar)
labvar_temp <- enquo(labvar)
p<- plot_ly(data = dataset, labels = ~labvar_temp, values = ~summvar_temp , type ="pie",hole = 0.6)
p
}

function_ringchart(df, "person","msgcount")
```

The following code however works fine and **returns the correct chart** (without varying the values variable):

```
function_ringchart<- function(dataset, labvar){
#summvar_temp <- enquo(summvar)
labvar_temp <- enquo(labvar)
p<- plot_ly(data = dataset, labels = ~labvar_temp, values = ~msgcount, type ="pie",hole = 0.6)
p
}

function_ringchart(df, "person")
```

Wondering what the reason is for the first set of code not working, or how to correctly use variable inputs for the `values =~` component of `plot_ly`?

Comment: Does this work?
function_ringchart<- function(dataset, labvar, summvar){
summvar_temp <- enquo(summvar)
labvar_temp <- enquo(labvar)
p<- plot_ly(labels = dataset[[labvar_temp]], values = dataset[[summvar_temp]] , type ="pie",hole = 0.6)
p
}

function_ringchart(df, "person","msgcount")

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. example data, please - otherwise this turns into guess work, merci

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
function_ringchart<- function(dataset, labvar, summvar){ 
  plot_ly(data = dataset, labels = dataset[,labvar])[[1]],
              values = dataset[,summvar])[[1]], type ="pie",
              hole = 0.6) 

} 
function_ringchart(economics, labvar = "date",  summvar = "pop")
```

If the data is in a tibble, it is obviously not rendering anything, so you have to either grab the values with `dataset[,summvar])[[1]]`, or you could convert to matrix aswell.